Camera not working with Ubuntu 24.04
Using Ubuntu 24.04 OS, my laptop camera is not working. Although my camera is enabled but it is still not working (opens as a black screen). I searched for solutions and tried cheese, snapshot and even vlc but it still opens as a black screen. Note that when I use a USB camera, it works normally. What is the solution or should I use an older version of Ubuntu?

In some places you say Ubuntu 24.04 in others you say Kubuntu 24.04 Please edit the question and clarify what product you are asking about.

This question is similar to: Camera not working. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I was getting Camera not found error after I updated my Ubuntu to 24.04 LTS.
The camera was working fine when using Google Meet etc(via the web), meanwhile, the snapshot showed this error.
This error was resolved using the below commands
sudo apt update
systemctl --user restart pipewire
snapshot

Reffered from https://askubuntu.com/a/1515774/1722193

unfortunately, this solution didn't solve my problem. But when I used usb camera it works fine. Also, my laptop camera is already installed and read as /dev/video0, /dev/video1. And when trying to open it, only black screen opens.

I'm sorry the solution didn't work for you, It worked for me that's why I added it as an answer, if it helps you can check if the ubuntu is fully updated as in all the ubuntu-drivers are installed, can check the system logs with journalctl -xe command too

If the "Camera" app doesn't work for you...
Add yourself to the "video" group and it'll work fine.
adduser your_username video
Then you MUST log out, then use this command to check if you're in the video group:
groups
If you don't show up there, then you MUST reboot.
